# Is Prime95 a dual-core tool?

Tags: multi-core, benchmarking, prime95

Does Prime95 use multiple cores? (Is there a difference in this regard between running it from Windows, UBCD, or UBCD4Win?)

If it doesn't, are there tools out there that will (preferably via a boot disc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Prime95 utilizes multiple cores.  Just turn up the 'thread count' option to at least as many cores as you'd like to test.

As long as the OS you choose to run it on sees your multiple cores, Prime95 should use them.

Comment: @techie007: So, does it do this from a boot disc as well? Say, UBCD4Win? Thanks!

Comment: NP, just ensure you have a newer UBCD, built with at least XP SP2 and a newer Prime95 (http://www.mersenne.org/) and you should be good. :)

Comment: @techie007: UBCD or UBCD4Win? (The two are not the same. Your using the build method for UBCD4Win [I think] and the UBCD name.) Thanks!

Comment: @Ssvarc According to the UBCD homepage (http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), UBCD still uses v23.5.2 of Prime95, which does not have built-in multi-threaded support.

Comment: @Ssvarc - I was referring to UBCD4Win - Sorry. :)  UBCD4Win has Prime95 v25.8.3.0 as of v3.50 (4/21/09). Plus you should be able to build v25.9 into it if needed.

Comment: @techie007: Thanks for the info! (To send someone a message use this format @username: [example @ssvarc:].)

Comment: @techie007: How would I go about building it into UBCD4Win (yes, I need it afterall:-)?

Answer (score 1):

When running a torture test in a recent version of Prime95, the `Number of torture threads to run` can be varied. I believe it defaults to the number of CPU cores on the machine.

[image: Prime95 options]